VS Code not opening any folder or showing any file
(https://i.sstatic.net/Dd2n21w4.png)my VS Code all on a sudden started showing like this. It is not showing any folder, not opening any folder or creating any files; also the live server is not working. Any help would be great. Thank you (https://i.sstatic.net/oJludnJA.png)
I tried already reinstalling the VS Code, there are no current updates.
